# Can Gradle still build C with the new plugins?

Tags: c, gradle

When I search for how to build C with Gradle, [official docs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/native_software.html) come up with the following info, explicitly mentioning C:

> The native software plugins add support for building native software components, such as executables or shared libraries, from code written in C++, C and other languages.

But also this info:

> The (...) plugins mentioned in this chapter will eventually be deprecated and removed. We recommend new projects looking to build C++ applications and libraries use the newer replacement plugins.

The [linked general docs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/building_cpp_projects.html) for the replacement plugins only mention C++, and the dedicated plugin docs for [cpp-application](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/cpp_application_plugin.html) and [cpp-library](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/cpp_library_plugin.html) are even explicit about C++ file extensions.

However, a [third-party site](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/gradle-support.html) states:

> Gradle is a build automation system that provides plugins to build C/C++ libraries and applications. (...) based on cpp-application and cpp-library plugins (...)

So is it still possible to build pure C applications and libraries with Gradle plugins that are not being retired, particularly with cpp-application and cpp-library?

*In case the answer is somehow obvious, please note I am not a C/C++ developer.*